# Can not install Samba in raspbian(debian)

Tags: linux, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

When I type in the command "sudo apt-get install samba",the answer is shown like "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 samba : Depends: libwbclient0 (= 2:3.6.6-6+deb7u5) but 2:4.1.17+dfsg-2 is to be installed
         Recommends: tdb-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
"
But I can install samba-common. All is based on raspberry pi 2 installed raspbian(based on debian)

Comment: This seems like a Linux question more than programming. Why ask here?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist sorry!

Comment: No need to apologize just suggesting you either (a.) refocus your question about programming to get better help here, or (b.) try somewhere like [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com) for better results.

Comment: What have you done to achieve that? If that's really broken packages, then it belongs to Raspbian's bug tracker. If that's something that you did with the system, at the very least, please describe what have you done, what have you tried to fix it, etc.

Comment: @GreyCat install samba winbind, and I changed the source of apt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the sources will cause this problem i have tested, so i think you should replace the offical sources of you modified sources.